# mysqli_fetch_row() returns false when mysqli_query() returns true

Tags: php, mysqli

I am currently trying to read data from multiple tables in a database and display the result in a tabular form.

But `mysqli_query()` returns `true` and `mysqli_fetch_row()` returns false.
`$link` is the connection object which has been initialized.

Code Snippet 1 :

```
$sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM users_list, user_personal_details, user_bank_details
    WHERE
        users_list.email = user_personal_details.email AND
        users.email=userbank_details.email
    LIMIT $num_rec_per_page
    OFFSET $start_from"; 

$rs_result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if ($rs_result == false) {  
    echo "Query failed";
    exit();
}
else echo "Query successful";
```

Code Snippet 2 :

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result);
if ($row == false)
    echo "Invalid";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result)) { 
    echo "In loop";
    $name = $row['name'];
    $date_added = $row['date_added'];
    echo $name;
    echo $date_added;
}
```

A `mysqli_fetch_row()` has been used outside the loop for debugging purposes.
The message **Query successful** is printed.
The message **Invalid** is printed.
What could be the reason?

Comment: May be your query returns true but may be possible it does't return any result .Use `mysqli_num_rows()` to check number of rows return by your query

Comment: And your are fetch row two times

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_row()` returns `array` not a `boolean` e.g. `$row=mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result);
        if($row==false)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your query returns true but may be possible it does't return any result .Use `mysqli_num_rows()` to check number of rows return by your query.

And don't fetch rows two times

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_list,user_personal_details,user_bank_details where users_list.email=user_personal_details.email and users.email=userbank_details.email LIMIT $num_rec_per_page OFFSET $start_from";
    $rs_result = mysqli_query($link, $sql); //run the query
    if ($rs_result == false) {
        echo "Query failed";
        exit();
    } else {
        $data = mysqli_num_rows($rs_result);
        if ($data > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result)) {
                $name = $row['name'];
                $date_added = $row['date_added'];
                echo $name;
                echo $date_added;
            }
        } else {
            echo "No result found";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You call mysqli_fetch_row() two times, and probably you get `false` on the second one.